# Show Grid gridlines as solid line not in dashed format in Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, telerik

I'm new to silverlight i have situation that in the grid i have to show vertical lines the below code which i have written displays dotted lines but i need solid line(s).This grid was declared in the telerik RadGridView.

```
             <grid>
                 <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>

                          <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <!--<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White"></Border>-->
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Text=""  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Source="" Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Source="" Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


  </Grid>
```

I have used border but it is after the column definition but each row border is been applying i just want a solid line instead of dotted or using border or rectangle controls.Please can any one provide me the solution.

Thanks

Haraveer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are wanting to do is to wrap each textblock/image with a border.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />

        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White"></Border>-->
    <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="3">
        <Image Width="15"
                Height="15"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="4">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="5">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="6">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="7">
        <Image Width="15"
                Height="15"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Grid.Column="8">
        <TextBlock Text=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>


</Grid>
```

Result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/niMWZ.png]

Comment: Hi bmeredith thanks for the rply i have tried using your code but it shows like                                                                   |           |              |                 |              |              |              |                 |                             |                 |                                                                    like lines with breaks it is better than dotted lines